# How do I map a dictionary with list values to a dataframe?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I need to map a dict to a column in a dataframe but don't know how to do it when the values in the dict are in a list. Ideally I was a new column for the values in pos `[0]`, and another column for the values in pos `[1]`.

```
dict = {'foo':['A','B'],
        'bar':['C','D']}

df = pd.DataFrame([[0,'foo'],
                   [1,'bar']], columns=['Col1','Col2'])
```

Below is the usual way I'd go about this task if there was only one dict value.

```
df['Col3'] = df.Col2.map(dict)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Series.map() will also accept functions, so you can pass in a lambda function that wraps the lookup dictionary and grabs the list item you want.

```
dict = {'foo':['A','B'],
        'bar':['C','D']}

df = pd.DataFrame([[0,'foo'],
                   [1,'bar']], columns=['Col1','Col2'])

df['Col3'] = df.Col2.map(lambda x: dict[x][0])
df['Col4'] = df.Col2.map(lambda x: dict[x][1])
```

Comment: Perfect. I thought it could have been accomplished with lambdas. Glad it's that easy.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, it's probably easiest to just turn the dictionary into a dataframe and use `pd.DataFrame.merge`:

```
In [40]: d = {'foo':['A','B'],
    ...:      'bar':['C','D']}

In [41]: df.merge(pd.DataFrame(d, index=["Col3", "Col4"]).T, 
                  left_on='Col2', right_index=True)
Out[41]:
   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0     0  foo    A    B
1     1  bar    C    D
```

Comment: Thanks. What does the .T do? Also what would you do if you didn't want all the values of the list merged?

Comment: .T does a transpose since by default, `pd.DataFrame` will try to make the dictionary keys into columns. `merge` essentially acts like a SQL join, so fields in Col2 that aren't used will be ignored.